# Tiny_tds gem on Ruby 2.0.0 fails - libiconv missing on Windows x64

Tags: ruby, windows, iconv, libiconv

It looks like a frequent error, but after 2 days, I still did not find the definite solution to this issue.

I installed Ruby 2.0.0-p451 (x64) and DevKit (DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe) from RubyInstaller for Windows. Ruby -v returns:

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [x64-mingw32]
```

Now, I run gem install tiny_tds, which returns:

```
E:\>gem install tiny_tds
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing tiny_tds:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

E:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Actually, the only libiconv I have on my system is E:\Ruby200\bin\libiconv-2.dll

I tried all I could find around without success, but I'm sure there is a smart answer to this. Can you please help me find it ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Fred

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Comment: Yes, I also tried this one. It does not solve the issue ... Anything more recent, for Win64 ? Thanks.

Comment: Would the E:\Ruby200\bin\libiconv-2.dll installed by Ruby be equivalent ? Could it be a path issue ? Thanks.